# text-decoration: underline - Not working in Android Webview

Tags: android, css, input, webview, text-decorations

I want the text underlined inside the input text box. So, I used this css

```
input {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

It works fine in my browser. But I can't see the underline in Android Webview. I tried chrome remote debugging. The CSS property is faded - guess it is not applied.

Someone know why it is not working in Webview. Suggestions or workarounds are welcome.

**EDIT**

Text box **without** `text-decoration: underline;`

[image]

Text box with `text-decoration: underline;`

[image]

I can't see the same behaviour in Android webview. (I don't see underline there)

Comment: It's a little weird having text underlined inside an input. Can you maybe send an example or image demonstrating this? Or when it looks acceptable?

Comment: @Gofilord I have edited the question. Can you please have a look at it again.

Comment: Probably the WebView doesn't support it. I can't seem to think of a workaround because what you are asking is pretty weird and unreasonable. In terms of user experience, why would the user want his text to be underlined as he is typing it?